# move google map to the left on marker click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I click on a marker I don't want to center the map on the marker but move it to a bit to the left so I can display a window with some information on the right. I think it would be easier to use setCenter() but then I need a position next to the marker.

I guess i would have to do some calculations based on the markers latitude and longitude but I do not know how to proceed with this. Does anyone know how to calculate to a position based on a markers latitude and longitude? or is there another (easier) way?

Comment: I have no idea how to get started so I don't have any code to show. I'm not asking for ready to go code but a gentle nudge in the right direction. I need to calculate a particular position (lat and long) based on an existing lat and long so my google map code does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to the marker.

Once marker is clicked, get marker position using `getPosition()`. To move the map to the left you want to center the map to a point to the right of the marker. So make a new set of coordinates with same lat and lng + 1 degree maybe.

Then you can use `setCenter()` or `panTo()` methods to move to the map in your desired direction.

Comment: Well that is the easy part which I already planned on doing. It is the lat and lng + 1 degree, like you call it, that i have no idea how to do. it's the calculation of that new position that I need to know.

Comment: `var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( oldLatLng.lat(), oldLatLng.lng()+1)`... maybe add a boundary condition for lng=180 degrees.